# The program allows the user to process the loop as long as user input an odd number

Tags: c++, c

can u help me with this question:
The program allows the user to process the loop as long as user input an odd number. When the user input an even number, display an appropriate message to terminate the program.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:
Enter an integer number : 5
Enter the next integer number : 7
Enter the next integer number : 9
Enter the next integer number : 2
You have entered an even number to terminate the program.

This is the coding that i did;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    {
    for(n = 1; n%2!=0; n++)
    cout<<"Enter a number:";
    cin>>n;

    if (n % 2 != 0; n++)
    {
    cout<<"Enter another number:";
    cin>>n;
    }
}

    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
    cout<<"The program is terminated...";
}
}
```

Comment: What did you try and where do you struggle? Please show your code.

Comment: This is not the "do my homework" forum. If you have questions regarding programming we will definitely help you! So please post what you already have achieved and clarify in your question what is not working as expected.

Comment: think how do you distinguish between odd and even numbers and use it

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? Determining whether a number is even, or using that fact to terminate a loop, or something else?

Comment: i tried to do the coding. my problem is the program doesnt ask to enter another number for the third time venthough i entered odd number.

Comment: Don't change n "manually", use it only to hold user input. You only need to change the for loop to a while loop with the condition you use in the for loop, and remove the if & inside the loop

Comment: @mutableVoid the instruction was to use for loop... what do you mean by 'dont change n manually'. im sorry im still new to coding.

Comment: @Alias the thing is that you don't really need a for loop here, as you just take the user's input and check if the condition is met in a `while` loop. If you exchange your code in the parenthesis after "int n" by the following you are good to go (if you insist on using a for loop):     cout<<"Enter a number:";
for (cin >> n; n % 2 != 0; cin >> n)
  cout << "Enter another number:";

Comment: Look closely at your indentation.  What is the body of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use the do-while loop and write all your conditions inside it.
Then the program will run till the user enters the even number.